# Rolles theorem question involving integrals

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous in $[a,b]$ and $g(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ then
>   $$\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
>   is
>   $$
> \begin{array}{lll}
> (a)\quad&g(\xi)\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx\quad&\text{for exactly one }\xi\in(a,b)\\
> (b)&f(\xi)\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx&\text{for all }\xi\in(a,b)\\
> (c)\quad&f(\xi)\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx\quad&\text{for some }\xi\in(a,b)\\
> (d)\quad&g(\xi)\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx\quad&\text{for all }\xi\in(a,b)\\
> \end{array}
> $$

I am sensing rolles theorem but i haven't found  way yet .Thanks

Comment: I have updated your question to use mathjax, please check that I did not change the meaning of your question.

Comment: @Kristoffer thanks

Comment: An alternate approach is the multiple choice exclusion principle: find the answers which are obviously wrong. Since the integral is constant and $f, g$ need not be it can be neither b) nor d). Since no injectivity assumptions are made regarding $g$, a) can be ruled out, as well...

Comment: @Thomas but a is given to be correct answer

Comment: a) is wrong. Choose $g= x^2$ and $f(x)=1$ on the interval $[-1,1]$. You will find two values of $\xi$, such that the equality a) holds.

Comment: Ok, let be $g(x)=1$ and $f(x)=3$, so you say that a) is right. Maybe you should reflect a little bit more before claiming this.

Comment: @Karl yes i see now i was thinking about function to apply rolles  , but now i see with counter examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$\min_y f(y) \int g(x)dx \le \int f(x)g(x) dx\le \max_y f(y)\int g(x) dx$$
(here it is used that $g\ge 0$)
and $\min$ and $\max$ are attained you can apply the mean value theorem. Since $f$ is continuos and the domain of definition is compact, there are values $c, d$ such that $f(c)=\min_y f(y)$ an $f(d) =\max_y f(y)$.

This implies that for any value $\eta$ sucht that $$\min_y f(y) \int g(x)dx=f(c)\int g(x) dx\le \eta\le f(d)\int g(x)dx=\max_y f(y)\int g(x) dx$$ there is $\xi \in [c,d]$ such that $f(\xi)\int g(x) dx= \eta$. Now chose $\eta = \int f(x)g(x) dx$

Comment: Hello I have not understood  , can youadd little more details

Comment: @SophieClad I added an explanation

Comment: so a b c are incorrect using counter examples , so d is correct ?

Comment: @SophieClad no, c) is correct.

Comment: thanks for helping, didn't understand your proof though .but counter examples solved my question , can you suggest suitable title for this Q.thanks

Comment: @SophieClad Maybe 'A mean value property for integrals'. What is it you did not understand?

Comment: actually i havenot studied mean value theorem for integrals , that is why not getting

Comment: @SophieClad You only need the mean value theorem for continous functions, in this case $f$.

Comment: i see now , thanks

Comment: the example you have given for removal of option a , why have you choosen such functions and interval , i mean how do you know ? Or udid  hit and trial

Comment: @SophieClad regarding the example: $\int_a^b f$ is a constant, so in order to find exactly one such $\xi$ the function $g$ needs to attain that particular value exactly once. So I searched for a $g$ which takes on almost every value twice, like $g(x)=x^2$, and a domain of definition where most values are taken on twice. The only point for which this $g$ has a unique value is $x=0$, and it is easy to see that that point cannot be the value with the desired property, if $f$ is constant, since it is the point where $g$ takes on it's minimal value.

Comment: ok thanks i unserstood

Answer (score 1):

While I'm thinking over (a) and (c)  I do think that (b) and (d) are wrong.

Just check with an easy example:

Let $ f(x) = x $ and $ g(x) = x $ where $ [a,b] = [0,1] $. Then $ \int\limits_a^b f(x)g(x) dx = \int\limits_a^b x^2 dx = \frac 1 3 (b^3 - a^3) = \frac 1 3 $.

Obviously (b) and (d) won't hold for $ \int\limits_a^b f(x)dx = \frac 1 2 $ or $ \int\limits_a^b g(x)dx  = \frac 1 2 $.

**Edit:** This is only to disprove (b) and (d) by counter example.

Comment: $f, g$ are arbitray. You must not pick a certain choice.

Comment: @kummerer94 thanks for helping